# Eclipse results in Failed to create Java Virtual Machine

Tags: android, eclipse

Please note I have already gone through previous similar threads.

I made all appropriate changes in eclipse.ini file mentioned in various thread. But still giving same error.

Here is my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-vm F:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw //Here also tried with javaw.exe but no luck
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: When running on shell do you get any specific error? Can you post it?

Comment: From the look of it you have a 64 bit JVM and a 32 bit Eclipse. You must run all 64 bit or all 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the -XX:MaxPermSize=512M line